# how to know async method finish working?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sqlite

How to know async methods finish working? I need all my objects in console.log(resp) but in result i only get [] an empty array.

```
var sqlite = require("sqlite3");
var db = new sqlite.Database(process.cwd() + "/cb.db");
var resp = [];

db.serialize(function() {
    db.each("SELECT * from user", function(err, data) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = data.user;
        resp.push(obj);
    });
 console.log(resp); 
});
```

Comment: `sqlite`'s [`Database#each`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete) accepts a 2nd callback function, `complete`, with the arguments, `function (err, rowCount)`.

Comment: async tasks usually always tell you when they´re finished. Jonathan Lonowski knows which one it fires in this case.

Comment: Thanx for your answers friends now i found a path to go with.

Answer (score 0):

move your `console.log` to be inside of the db callback

```
var sqlite = require("sqlite3");
var db = new sqlite.Database(process.cwd() + "/cb.db");
var resp = [];

db.serialize(function() {
    db.each("SELECT * from user", function(err, data) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = data.user;
        resp.push(obj);
        console.log(resp); 
    });
});
```

the function runs whenever the db call finishes.  Previously you were running your console.log before the db read was done, so your db results were not in your array.